# Count Down with event over 2 weeks

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I have a program that is basically to assign dinners over my family. What I like to add is a count down that I put a date and, over 2 weeks repeats an event that quit a person in my family. This is what I've done so far:

```
#Programa de Python para ver el reparto de cenas

import time

import datetime

from datetime import datetime, timedelta; #countdays

fecha = datetime.today () #hoy

quien =  'Pirulo'

while fecha <= datetime(2016, 3, 31): #condicion while loop

    nodays = fecha.weekday() #los dias en numeros

    if quien=='Pitulo':
        quien = 'Mengana'
    elif quien=='Mengana':
        quien = 'Fulana'
    elif quien=='Fulana':
        quien = 'Sultana'
    elif quien=='Sultana':
        quien = 'Pirulo'   

    if quien == 'Sultana' and (nodays == 1 or nodays == 3):
        quien = 'Fulana'

    print (fecha.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') + ': ' + quien + " /"+str(nodays)) #el out en la pantalla

    fecha += timedelta(days=1) #que al dia anterior le suma uno mas
```

What I want is that 'Fulana' is quitted of the family over 2 weekends.

Comment: En español, que significan "quit a person in my family" e "'Abril' is quitted of the family over 2 weekends"? Son confuso en engles.

Comment: Quitar una persona de la familia... O sea, que no la considere a 'Abril' cada semana de por medio

Comment: What someone said to me is that I have to make a variable that is True, then False, True, then False, over and over... So, for example, if a Friday is true, 'Abril' counts in the family, then the other Friday has to be False, so 'Abril' doesn´t count in the family

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to make it so that "Abril" is only included in the rotation only every other week. You could try creating a condition and then switching that condition's value every time a new week rolls around. Then include "Abril" when the condition is `True` and do not include her when the condition is `False`. Something like:

```
condition = True  # your new condition
while ...:  # your main while loop
  nodays = fecha.weekday()

  # Switch condition on Sunday
  if nodays == 6:
    condition = not condition

  # Update quien
  if quien=='Ale':
    quien = 'Judith'
  elif quien=='Judith':
    quien = 'Jazmin'
  elif quien=='Jazmin':
    quien = 'Abril'
  elif quien=='Abril':
    quien = 'Ale'

  # Check if we are including 'Abril'
  if quien=='Abril' and not condition:  # replace 'Abril'
    quien = 'Ale'  # skip over 'Abril' for this rotation

  ...
```

Maybe this helps. Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @Jaz_GV great to hear! Would you mind sharing your solution and marking it as the answer? This helps people down the line who might have a similar issue. You can select "Answer your own question" or something like that at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was this:

```
if (nodays == 0):
    if findes == False:
        findes = True
    else:
        findes = False
```

So on Mondays the variable findes change, and if the variable was false:

```
if (nodays == 4 or nodays == 5 or nodays == 6) and findes == False:
    if cena3 == 'Jazmin':
        cena3 = 'Judith'
    elif cena3 == 'Judith':
        cena3 = 'Alejandro'
    elif cena3 == 'Alejandro':
        cena3 = 'Jazmin'
```

Abril would be cut out of the family :D. I can't imagine this was THAT simple, and i'd think it was mission impossible...